# In Pandas, how can I replace a subset of the dataframe with another subset of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Suppose I have a dataframe, where every 5th row is filled with NAs, like this:

| Number | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | NA | NA | NA |
| 6 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 100 | 3 | 5 | 2 |

I want to replace the NA values you can find in the 5th row with the values in the 3rd row.

What I've tried so far:

```
df.loc[df['Number'] % 5 == 0, ['A','B','C']] = df.loc[df['Number'] % 3 == 0, ['A','B','C']]
```

This approach does not throws any error, but it does nothing. Howewer, if I replace the right side of the assignment with a constant, it works fine, like this:

```
df.loc[df['Number'] % 5 == 0, ['A','B','C']] = 3
```

Any idea on how to make it work?

EDIT:

I did not want to give the full original task, howewer this dummy example is a little bit wrong. So let's assume that the right side has as many rows as the left side. The main objective is still, to replace every 5th row's values with a subset of the dataframe based on conditions. I hope it is a little bit more understandable, and sorry for the miscralification.

Comment: *Every third row* would imply multiple rows. I.e., you could have more rows on the right-hand side of the assignment than on the left-hand side.

Comment: incorrect index alignment of the left and right hand sides...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexes are misaligned that's why it doesn't work:

```
# Left hand side
>>> df.loc[df['Number'] % 5 == 0, ['A','B','C']]
     A    B    C
1  NA   NA   NaN
3   3    5   2.0

# Right hand side
>>> df.loc[df['Number'] % 3 == 0, ['A','B','C']]
    A   B    C
2  5   6   7.0
```

Pandas can't align index between (1, 3) and 2. The solution is to convert the right hand side to numpy array with `.values` or `.to_numpy()`. However if you do this, you also change the fourth row.

Update:

> So let's assume that the right side has as many rows as the left side

In this case, use:

```
df.loc[df['Number'] % 5 == 0, ['A','B','C']] = \
    df.loc[df['Number'] % 3 == 0, ['A','B','C']].values
```

```
# Before (I slightly modified your example)
>>> df
   Number    A    B    C
0       3  2.0  1.0  0.0
1       5  NaN  NaN  NaN
2       6  5.0  6.0  7.0
3     100  NaN  NaN  NaN

# After
>>> df
   Number    A    B    C
0       3  2.0  1.0  0.0
1       5  2.0  1.0  0.0
2       6  5.0  6.0  7.0
3     100  5.0  6.0  7.0
```

Comment: @NeverSayEver. I updated my answer related to your edit. Can you check it please?

Comment: Yup, now its working, thank you very much! I feel a little bit ashamed that the solution was just this simple, and I was trying to figure it out for a day now. :')

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Number': [3, 5, 6, 100],
    'B': [2, np.nan, 5, 3],
    'C': [1, np.nan, 6, 5],
    'D': [0, np.nan, 7, 2]
}).set_index('Number')

idx = df[df.isna().all(axis=1)].index
df.loc[idx] = df.loc[idx - 2].values
```

Comment: This approach also works, thank you very much! :)